# Python requests with a raw body

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

Apologies if this is a repost/stupid question, I have tried searching around but found nothing.

I have a cgi webserver that takes a POST payload that is neither percentage encoded or form data. i.e, I need to stop the request from being percentage encoded, as with:

```
req = Request('POST', license_url, data={ None: data})
```

And I also need the request to not include the multiform boundaries introduced by:

```
req = Request('POST', license_url, file={ None: file_handle})
```

My request body looks something like:

```
abc
def
ghi=
```

And this is exactly what I want to post to the server (Postman achieves this when set to raw payload).

However, sending through the data param looks like:

```
data=abc%3Adef%3a..
```

And through the file Param:

```
--b70cc8bd5ac1411488c719a1d773edde
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="blahblah"

abc
def
ghi=

--b70cc8bd5ac1411488c719a1d773edde
```

^^^ This is the closest to what I need but I also want to strip the boundary/content-disposition terms (not on the server).

Many Thanks

Comment: can you send it as bytes: `b'abc\ndef\nghi='`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just post the raw text content like

```
req = Request('POST', license_url, data=data.encode())
```

provided the `data` is a string.